# How to output variable when use filter?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to check what I got in `$file`.

I found simlar question here, but not work in this case.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51145/get-php-variable-from-functions-php-and-echo-it-in-theme-template-files

Can someone help me ? or give me a keyword.

WordPress `functions.php`

```
function wp_modify_uploaded_file_names($file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file['name']);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($file['name'], $ext);

    $file['name'] = uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method

    print_r($file);

   return $file;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wp_modify_uploaded_file_names', 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single parameter, `$file`, represent a single element of the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array. You can access The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server via `$file['tmp_name']`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but If I want to echo a word when filter working, how ?

Comment: Try to use `wp_die( print_r($file, true) )`.

Comment: Like nothing happened ?

Comment: Only wordpress's system error message, I found it use Ajax to upload file

Comment: So look at the Browser Dev tools -> network (your ajax request) -> preview ;)

Comment: Thanks you, it really helpful :)